# how can i make setpixel like method in wpf?

Tags: wpf, writeablebitmap

I need a very fast method to update bitmap, something like setpixel in wpf. I don't know much about imaging in wpf ? I made my own method but it is very-very slow.

I also tried to use http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/, but it is for Silverlight and their is no property like Pixels in wpf's `writablebitmap`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455004/wpf-how-to-efficiently-update-an-image-30-times-per-second)